How would you replace this 3-way T valve?
Replacing the valve on a cold water pipe under a household sink.
The 3-way T valve is used to divert water through a drinking water filter and back again.
I'm replacing the tap and filter, this includes replacing the 3-way T valve. The current one (as you can see in the pics) is secured to the copper pipes with pieces of what looks to me like black temporary pipe.



New valve.

I'm assuming it wouldn't be possible to re-use the black pipe as the connections are not threaded and would not be compatible with the new valve.
Would this include fitting new sections of copper pipe and soldering them in place?
Any insights or instructions would be appreciated!
Edit:
Why I'm not sure if it's possible to just keep this valve and replace the filter:
The hoses which are attached to the current valve and filter are the flexi-hoses you can see in the picture below (left).
The new valve/filter setup uses white plastic tubes attached with quick connects (one of these quick connects can be seen in the pic of the new valve above).
Below (right) is the picture of the new filter setup and white plastic tube connection (pic only shows one tube connection on the right side but when finished there would be one on each side of the filter head).


So using the new filter with the old valve I don't think is feasible due to the mismatch in pipes/tubes.


The white valve has four ports.  Your new one as three.  How did you choose this new valve?  2) Why are you replacing the valve at all?  It looks to me like the job of the old one is to either send water to the valve AND BACK, or to not do that, and pass it straight through.   The latter being .... maybe, I don't know ... so you can change the filter?  Why change the valve?  It looks to be in good condition.  3) If an equivalent metal-bodied valve is available, which I doubt, you'll have to replace EVERYTHING.  The brass and black adapters and the hoses too.  Nothing is compatible.


Who made the water filter? Did you consider contacting them to see if they sell the 4 way as a service part?

You could use two of those 3-way valves to replicate the function except you have to remember to operate both instead of just one...

@SolarMike Just don't forget to turn both of them!

Also, if this kind of arrangement was for a whole house filter I'd understand but if it's just for a drinking spout, why can't you use a normal shutoff valve?  Why must you provide bypassed water to the sink during the 10 minutes it takes to change the filter?

@jay613 "except you have to remember to operate both" so I covered that...

@jay613 I've updated the post with some context about why I don't think replacing the filter without changing the valve would be possible. Otherwise that would be a great idea (and embarrassingly I hadn't thought of it).

Also, in case this helps - the faucet head has 3 levers.. hot, cold and filtered.

Ah ok so you need new hoses and valve.   You may need to change the valve fittings for the new valve.  Get a bypass valve not a diverter. Though, your old valve might accommodate the new hoses, perhaps with an adapter?  Worth looking into before replumb8ng

Just replace the filter https://thetapfactory.com/shop/accessories-spares/spares/replacement-filter-cartridge/
